# Use PHP while loop to create advance filter

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a problem and that is I want to create a link on a website like people can click the link to show certain products only depending on percentage. like for example, i have a column in my database with discount percentage and it will show min discount and max discount. assuming we have min and max discount. $min=12 and $max=94; and I want to put them in links to show only products with certain discounts only like filtering. below is the example of the link.

```
    <a href="#">12% to 20%</a
    <a href="#">21% to 30%</a>
    <a href="#">31% to 40%</a> and so on until it reaches 
    <a href="#">81% to 90%</a> and the last will be 
    <a href="#">91% to 94%</a>
```

smallest and largest numbers will be coming from a column from database and they can change frequently. i came up with solution and its working fine but my code is too long and its like I took to many steps which could be done in few lines of code. I have pasted my working code below but I am sure this can be reduced to few lines of code.

```
$catsql25 = "SELECT MAX(down_percentage) as largest FROM hot_deals";
$catquery25 = mysqli_query($conn, $catsql25);
while ($row25 = mysqli_fetch_array($catquery25, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $largest_number = $row25['largest'];
}

$catsql26 = "SELECT MIN(down_percentage) as smallest FROM hot_deals";
$catquery26 = mysqli_query($conn, $catsql26);
while ($row26 = mysqli_fetch_array($catquery26, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $smallest_number = $row26['smallest'];
}

$array_tens = array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100);


foreach ($array_tens as $value){

    if(($value - $smallest_number <= 10) && ($value - $smallest_number > 0)){
        echo '<a href="/exp.php?fst='.$smallest_number.'&lst='.$value.'"><div class="lfmen2">';
        echo $smallest_number." to ".$value."</div></a>";
        $next_num = $value + 1;
        $next_ten = 9;
        $stop_num = floor($largest_number / 10);
        $stop_num2 = $stop_num * 10;
        //echo $stop_num2.'<br>';
        $num_rounds = $stop_num2 - $value;
        $num_rounds2 = $num_rounds / 10;
        //echo $num_rounds2;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rounds2; $i++){
        $end_num = $next_num + $next_ten;
        echo '<a href="/exp.php?fst='.$next_num.'&lst='.$end_num.'"><div class="lfmen2">';
        echo $next_num;
        echo " to ";
        echo $end_num;
        echo "</div></a>";
        $next_num += 10;
        $end_num += 10;
        }
    }
}


foreach ($array_tens as $value2){

    if(($largest_number - $value2 < 10) && ($largest_number - $value2 > 0)){
        $lsst = $value2 + 1;
        if($lsst != $largest_number){
        echo '<a href="/exp.php?fst='.$lsst.'&lst='.$largest_number.'"><div class="lfmen2">'.$lsst." to ".$largest_number."</div></a>";
        }
        elseif($lsst == $largest_number){
            echo '<a href="/exp.php?fnly='.$largest_number.'"><div class="lfmen2">'.$largest_number.'</div></a>';
        }
    }

}
```

I know its all mess but..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you could do is only one SQL Query :

```
$catsql = "SELECT MAX(down_percentage) as largest, MIN(down_percentage) as smallest FROM hot_deals";
```

And then you'll need only one loop :

```
$catquery = mysqli_query($conn, $catsql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($catquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $largest_number = $row['largest'];
    $smallest_number = $row['smalest'];
}
```

After that, you could make only one foreach loop. The two "if" conditions could be in the same loop :

```
foreach ($array_tens as $value) {

    if (($value - $smallest_number <= 10) && ($value - $smallest_number > 0)) {
        echo '<a href="/exp.php?fst='.$smallest_number.'&lst='.$value.'"><div class="lfmen2">';
        echo $smallest_number." to ".$value."</div></a>";
        $next_num = $value + 1;
        $next_ten = 9;
        $stop_num = floor($largest_number / 10);
        $stop_num2 = $stop_num * 10;
        //echo $stop_num2.'<br>';
        $num_rounds = $stop_num2 - $value;
        $num_rounds2 = $num_rounds / 10;
        //echo $num_rounds2;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rounds2; $i++) {
            $end_num = $next_num + $next_ten;
            echo '<a href="/exp.php?fst='.$next_num.'&lst='.$end_num.'"><div class="lfmen2">';
            echo $next_num;
            echo " to ";
            echo $end_num;
            echo "</div></a>";
            $next_num += 10;
            $end_num += 10;
        }
    }

    if (($largest_number - $value < 10) && ($largest_number - $value > 0)) {
        $lsst = $value + 1;
        if ($lsst != $largest_number) {
            echo '<a href="/exp.php?fst='.$lsst.'&lst='.$largest_number.'"><div class="lfmen2">'.$lsst." to ".$largest_number."</div></a>";
        } elseif ($lsst == $largest_number) {
            echo '<a href="/exp.php?fnly='.$largest_number.'"><div class="lfmen2">'.$largest_number.'</div></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

To make it more readable, you could also comment your code to know what do what.

This and a good indentation and you're right.

Hope it helps.